# Please help with basic permutations problem

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I am trying to solve the following problem:

*Messages are encoded by flying flags of 5 different colors in a given order:

a) How many different messages are possible?

b) For how many messages will a red flag be above a blue one (assuming red and blue are among the 5 colors?*

**My reasoning:**
a) It can be seen that the answer has to be $5!=120 $

b) There are different possibilities depending on the placement of the blue flag, this gives me $4!+ 3*3!+2*3!+3!= 10*3!=60$. If, for example, you place it in the second position, then you only have three ways to put the red flag and 3! ways to place the other 3. However, according to my textbook, the answer should be 36. What's wrong with this reasoning? Is there another possible way to interpret the question?
**Thank you in advance!**

Comment: By symmetry, the number of orders with $R$ above $B$ must be the same as the number with $B$ above $R$, hence each case is half the total.  Did you possibly omit some other conditions on the order?  the phrasing is odd.. "*a* red flag" and "*a* blue flag" suggests that it's possible to duplicate colors.

Comment: Not really, that is maybe because  I am translating it from Spanish...I added the statement in parenthesis for clarity... it says explicitly that the colors of the flags are all different

Comment: Are you sure that, say, the problem didn't specify that a message consisted of $4$ colors, drawn from the $5$?   I think that works out to $36$ (I did it hastily, so might have got it wrong).

Comment: It could be interpreted as the red flag be *immediately* above the blue one, but in this case the arrangementes will be $4!=24$ (just think of RB as one single colour).

Comment: On the other hand it could mean *with at least another flag in between*. Then you'll have $60$ (as noted by @lulu) minus $24$ (my previous comment), i.e. $36$ :) I admit that this is a bit "fitting the problem to the solution".

Comment: @lulu Could you please show me the calculation?

Comment: For my reverse engineered solution?  Sure:  Say we want to make a $4-$flag message out of the $5$.  Given that $R,B$ must be among the chosen colors we need to choose two more out of the remaining three. There are $3$ ways to do that.  Then there are $4!=24$ ways to arrange the $4$.  We have $3\times 24=72$ ways to make a $4-$flag message containing both $R,B$ and, as before, exactly half of these have $R$ above $B$.

Comment: Should stress:  As with the interpretation provided by @AndreaMori, this really is reverse engineered to justify the official answer. It is, of course, perfectly possible that the official answer is simply wrong.